# Can a test account be created on the developer's phone?

Tags: android

In my game I have InApp Purchases. I want to test my game before publishing, so I uploaded it to alpha. I would love to test it on my phone, but google refuse, saying a developer can't buy his own products. Google also refuse to allow emulators to purshase items.

Yesterday I added a google account to my phone, and added it to the list of people allowed to download my app (Gmail accounts with testing access).

My problem is that I can't access my game (We're sorry, the requested URL was not found on this server). My game is available (I checked it from another phone and its good). I simply can't access it from my test account.

What can I do? Should I do something, or I will not be able to test my game on my phone no matter what?

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_testing.html) is the android developer help for testing in-app purchases. The second account you added should be able to access the game shortly. In my experience, it usually takes up to about 24 hours to access alpha/beta testing once a user has been added.

Here's some specific stuff from that post:

Test Purchases (In-app Billing Sandbox)

Test purchases offer a secure, convenient way to enable larger-scale testing of your In-app Billing implementation during development or in preparation for launch. They let authorized user accounts make purchases of your in-app products through Google Play without incurring any actual charges to the user accounts.

Once authorized for testing access, those users can make purchases without being charged. Test purchases are real orders and Google Play processes them in the same way as other orders. When purchases are complete, Google Play prevents the orders from going to financial processing, ensuring that there are no actual charges to user accounts, and automatically canceling the completed orders after 14 days.

We recommend that you first test your In-app Billing implementation using static responses from Google Play. This enables you to verify that your application is handling the primary Google Play responses correctly and that your application is able to verify signatures correctly. You can do this even if the app hasn't been published yet.

To test your implementation with static responses, you make an In-app Billing request using a special item that has a reserved product ID. Each reserved product ID returns a specific static response from Google Play. No money is transferred when you make In-app Billing requests with the reserved product IDs. Also, you cannot specify the form of payment when you make a billing request with a reserved product ID.

Comment: Now its been over 36 hours since I created the test account, and still it can't access my app. I also added a Google Wallet to the test account, and it also didn't help.